# How to write a function in views.py that could handle more than two button?

Tags: python, html, django

For example, I have three button in my templates,

```
   <button type="button" name = "remermber">I know that </button>
   <button type="button" name = "forget">Don't know </button>
   <button type="button" name = "not_appear">Too esay :)</button>
```

than I want to write a function in views.py that could judge different button user has clicked and implement different function.

I'm a very new student in code. I don't know  javascript and ajax, could I achieve this function just use python in Django?

the form.py

```
    class OptionForm(forms.Form):   
       action = forms.CharField()
```

the views.py

```
   def recite_words(request):
       if request.method == "GET":
            form = OptionForm(request.GET) 
           if form.is_valid():
                if form.cleaned_data["action"] == "remermber":
                     return HttpResponse("remermber") 
                elif form.cleaned_data["action"] == "forget":
                     return HttpResponse("forget")
                elif form.cleaned_data["action"] == "not_appear":
                      return HttpResponse("not_appear")   
           else:
                return HttpResponse("2")
       return HttpResponse("fail")
```

the recite_words.html

```
   {% extends 'tag_study/base.html' %}
   {% load staticfiles %}
   {% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
   {% block body_block %}
   {% endblock %}

    {% block side_block %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form action="" method="GET"> 
        <button type="button" name="action" value="remermber">I know that </button>
        <button type="button" name="action" value="forget">Don't &nbsp know </button>
        <button type="button" name="action" value="not_appear">Too esay :)</button>
        </form> 
   {% endif %}


    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, you can, you just need to know basic JS and HTML, you can write server side templates in Django. Call different views from different buttons

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan OP specifically asked if he could do it without JS.

Comment: If its without JS then you will have to change the button to href tag and then assign a django URL to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need (if you want to use forms) to have the same name for every button:

```
<button type="button" name="action" value="remermber">I know that </button>
<button type="button" name="action" value="forget">Don't know </button>
<button type="button" name="action" value="not_appear">Too esay :)</button>
```

Add this to your form:

```
action = forms.CharField()
```

Now you can use it in your view:

```
if form.cleaned_data["action"] == "remember":
    pass  # your code for remember action
elif form.cleaned_data["action"] == "forget":
    pass  # your code for forget action
```

If you don't want to use forms, you can access your button value via `request.POST .get("action")` or `request.GET.get("action")`:

Comment: I did some modified after your suggestion, but when I click the button it doesn't have reaction

Comment: @Fudun change type to submit

Comment: I use the try... except .. to find the problem ,it seems like the form.is_valid() always judge as false in the views.py.I add my code in the question description, if you can give me some advices that will be great ：）！

Comment: @Fudun, check out your console output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those buttons are inside a form with `method="POST"`, you can simply get the values from the POST dictionary and despatch accordingly:

```
if 'remember' in request.POST:
    return do_remember_function(request)
elif 'forget' in request.POST:
    return do_forget_function(request)
elif 'not_appear' in request.POST:
    return do_not_appear_function(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could.  Just check the `request.POST` for the parameter with the button name:

```
if 'remember' in request.POST:
    # "I know that" button was pressed
elif 'forget' in request.POST:
    # "Don't know" button was pressed
```